# Setting two date fields with a if statement

Tags: javascript, adobe, datefield

I have a rental lease form (adobe acrobat) with three different fields. One is a dropdown list where the user can select either a 1 year lease term or a 2 year lease term . The other two are date fields. The first one is a lease commencement date and the other one is a lease end date

What I'm trying to accomplish is when the user enters the lease commencement date it should automatically populate the second date field based on what the user choose in the lease term field.

So for example, if the lease start date is 01/01/2013 and the user chose a 1yr lease, then the end date should finish 12/31/**2014**. If, however the user chose a 2 year lease then the lease end date should be 12/31/**2015**.

Comment: and what did you tried?

Comment: I'm new at javascript so I don't really know how to work with dates yet.

Comment: try with something simple, this is advanced for you or take some tutorial.

Comment: I work at a real estate firm and my boss has asked me to get this for him ASAP. Any ideas to get this to work properly?